# Customizing runtimePath in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm using the Yii framework for a web app. I moved the runtime folder out of the protected folder and put it on the same level as the index.php file. Now in the main config file, main.php I added:

`'runtimePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'runtime',`

which is right underneath the basePath that is set correctly:

```
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
```

I made sure the runtime folder is writable. I'm using Godaddy with a Windows IIS7 server. This is the error I get: *Application runtime path "D:\Hosting\9434915\html\yii\picbridge\protected\config..\runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.*

I know its pointing to the wrong folder but how do I get it to point to the right folder? I used the same file path convention for runtimePath as for basePath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem I switched from a Windows hosting plan to a Linux. Right after I switched I used FileZilla to set folder permissons and the error went away. I think the problem had to do with the limited ability a user can set folder permissions in a Godaddy Windows shared hosting plan. A user can only set permissions using Godaddy's FTP File Manager, they can't set permissions using FileZilla like in a Linux shared hosting plan.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing slash after `..`.
Notice path in your error message, it is folder `config..` and then slash:
D:\Hosting\9434915\html\yii\picbridge\protected\config`..`\runtime
Should be:
D:\Hosting\9434915\html\yii\picbridge\protected\config`\..`\runtime
What is weird here, is that you have `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` after `dirname(__FILE__)`, and it *should* produce proper path.

**Hint:** [No need for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php#73954) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, just use `/` will work on any windows without problem, this is only usefull for parsing paths from filesystem.

**Hint2:** Thanks for *Eirik Hoem* comment, you should strictly separate protected files from public files. Personally i use folowwing layout:

```
/app/protected/
/app/www/
/framework/
```

Comment: I'd also consider moving everything in `protected` into root, then creating a new `webroot` folder in root. Place index, themes and web-accessible files in that folder, and remove `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

you should not put it in the index.php level, leave it in protected folder.

and within protected folder, use `.htaccess` with `deny from all` to prevent direct access to your `mvc style php code` which is not traditional `html output php code`.

check [application base directory](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-base-directory) for detail

Comment: I moved the runtime folder back into the protected folder and moved the protected folder to the same level as the framework folder. I followed Larry Ullman's blog post about it:[link](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/03/configuring-yii/). I still get the same error, "Application runtime path "D:\Hosting\9434915\html\yii\protected\runtime" is not valid." Does it matter that I didn't install yii in the main website directory? To get to yii the web address is www.mywebsite.com/yii.

Comment: If you get this error yii is installed properly, this is yii error, you sure this folder exists and is writable by php? If it's not that, then check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6259461/133408

Comment: I assume yii is installed properly since the webpage loads after I hit reload when I get the runtimepath error. The folder exists and is writeable. @PeterM The answer you reference is for an Apache server, I'm using a Windows IIS 7.0 server. Should it matter that I didn't install yii in the main webroot folder?

Comment: I does not matter if it's in root folder. Checked yii source for runtime path, and it checks if it exists, if it is dir and if it **is writable**. Can you write with plain php into that dir? like `file_put_contents` there or whatever?

Comment: I ran a test using the file_put_contents function and a plain text file inside the runtime folder. I was able to write to the plain text file that was inside the runtime folder. I was able to do it by hard-coding the file path to runtime. The file path I used is the same that comes up in the error message, "Application runtime path "D:\Hosting\9434915\html\yii\protected\runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process." I feel like its something to do with a Windows server setting but I can't figure out what.